# For every $k>2$, does there exist at least one k-perfect number?

Tags: number-theory

For every $k>2$, does there exist at least one number $n$ for which $\sigma(n)=k*n$? What kind of heuristics can be done to shed light on this problem?

Comment: what is $\sigma(n)$?

Comment: the sum of divisors function

Comment: From the least numbers $n$ up to $k=11$ on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiply_perfect_number), there seems to be an approximately exponential growth in the number of digits, very roughly $\log n\propto2.5^k$. From [Grönwall's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function#Growth_rate),

$$
\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\sigma(n)}{n\,\log \log n}=e^\gamma\;,
$$

we might expect $\log n\propto\mathrm e^k$.

Comment: Nobody knows whether there is, for every $k>2$, an integer $n$ for which $\sigma(n)=kn$.

Comment: Do we expect that there is? Why or why not?

Comment: For every $k$ there are infintely many numbers such that $\sigma(n) \ge kn$. So there are plenty of possibilities for $k$-perfect numbers ;)

Comment: Similar question just asked at MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/306545/are-multiperfect-numbers-of-the-same-abundancy-index-infinite-or-finite

Answer (score 2):

See Wikipedia's [k-perfect numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiply_perfect_number#Smallest_k-perfect_numbers):

> In mathematics, a multiply perfect number (also called multiperfect number or pluperfect number) is a generalization of a perfect number.
>
> For a given natural number k, a number n is called k-perfect (or k-fold perfect) if and only if the sum of all positive divisors of n (the divisor function, σ(n)) is equal to kn; a number is thus perfect if and only if it is 2-perfect. A number that is k-perfect for a certain k is called a multiply perfect number

$$
\small
    \begin{array}{rrl} \\
    k & \text{Smallest k-perfect number} &  \\
    \hline \\
    2 & 6 & 2 × 3 \\
    3 & 120 & 2^3 × 3 × 5 \\
    4 & 30240 & 2^5 × 3^3 × 5 × 7 \\
    5 & 14182439040 & 2^7 × 3^4 × 5 × 7 × 11^2 × 17 × 19 \\
    6 & \text{(21 digits)} \, 154345556085770649600 & 2^15 × 3^5 × 5^2 × 7^2 × 11 × 13 × 17 × 19 × 31 × 43 × 257 \\
    7 & ... & \\
    \end{array}
$$

See the Wikipedia page linked above for k-perfect numbers up to 11, they are too lengthy to fit on Stack Exchange pages. It's reasonable to expect that there are more but [they haven't been discovered](http://wwwhomes.uni-bielefeld.de/achim/mpn.html) yet.

Other references:

Oeis - [Multiply-Perfect Numbers](http://oeis.org/wiki/Multiply-perfect_numbers#Conjectured_number_of_k-perfect_numbers_for_each_k_.E2.89.A5_3)

MathWorld - [Multiperfect Number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MultiperfectNumber.html)

> "Moxham (2000) found the largest known multiperfect number, approximately equal to 7.3×10^(1345), on Feb. 13, 2000."

The "[The Multiply Perfect Numbers Page](http://wwwhomes.uni-bielefeld.de/achim/mpn.html)" has a gzipped file from 2014 with 5311 MPNs, as of 2018-01-07 no new numbers have been discovered.